# How can I set (and why is it not already set) the preview sink for the camera in my WinUI application?

Tags: c#, .net, camera, winui-3

I'm making a WinUI3 application, that displays a camera feed to the user, and can stop/start it with a button. So far I've followed the "tutorial" by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access). I have the following code in my application:

```
<MediaPlayerElement
x:Name="CaptureElement"
AutoPlay="True"
Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

```
cameraCapture = new MediaCapture();
var mediaCaptureInitializationSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
{
SourceGroup = cameraSourceGroup,
SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.ExclusiveControl,
StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu
};

await cameraCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaCaptureInitializationSettings);
var frameSource = cameraCapture.FrameSources[cameraSourceGroup.SourceInfos[0].Id];
CaptureElement.Source = Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource.CreateFromMediaFrameSource(frameSource);

await cameraCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

The last line throws an exceptions with this reason "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'An unexpected error has occurred in the operation requested.
Preview sink not set'"
From what I've gathered, the preview sink has already been set by `CaptureElement.Source = ...`, so I don't understand why it is throwing an exception.

I've tried looking for a solution, but another problem is that I can't find any relevant help, because even Microsoft links me back to UWP documentation to do this:

```
mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

PreviewControl.Source = mediaCapture;
await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

But in my case PreviewControl.Source is an `IMediaPlaybackSource` type, which the `MediaCapture` type is not. Similarly, this example uses a `CaptureElement` xaml element which I can't find.

My question is, how can I set the preview sink for the capture, so that I cant start/stop the preview on a button click?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx/pull/162) might be worth checking.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding thanks, but as far as I can see this suffers from the same problems I'm describing.